# How can I return the PolicyId Claim after executing my Custom SignUpSignIn policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like the policyId to be included in the claims that are returned when my Customized SignUpSignIn policy is executed.

I think this should be in claim Id `tfp`.

There [is an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-manage-sso-and-token-configuration) on how to do this.

In the section "Setting claim representing policy ID" it says to include the key `AuthenticationContextReferenceClaimPattern` in the "Token Issuer" ClaimsProvider override.

```xml
<ClaimsProviders>
  <ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
        <Metadata>
          .....
          <Item Key="AuthenticationContextReferenceClaimPattern">None</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
  </ClaimsProvider>
</ClaimsProviders>
```

And then you have to add the `trustFrameworkPolicy` in your `outputClaims`. I think like this:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
      ......
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="trustFrameworkPolicy" Required="true" DefaultValue="{policy}" />
    </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

But when I upload this Custom Policy file an error is displayed:

> "Policy "B2C_1A_xxxx" of tenant "yyyyy.onmicrosoft.com" makes a reference to ClaimType with id "trustframeworkPolicy" but neither the policy nor any of its base policies contain such an element."

Meaning it can't find the ClaimTypeReferenceId: "trustFrameworkPolicy".

Do I have to add a claim definition of the ClaimType "trustframeworkPolicy"? in the ClaimsSchema?

If so: What's it like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following `ClaimType` to `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="trustFrameworkPolicy">
    <DisplayName>Trust Framework Policy</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="tfp" />
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="tfp" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>
```

Note: `ClaimType` should be a child node of `<ClaimsSchema><BuildingBlocks>`

Comment: This was the correct answer! To include the PolicyName in the "tfp" claim I had to do the actions in my Question and add the claimType like @spottedmahn showed me.

Comment: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/issues/11) to get that `ClaimType` added to the starter pack.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have done the steps that are specified here. But I keep getting "{policy}" as the tfp value... Is there a fix for this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `PolicyId` is in the ACR claim when using the [Starter Pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack)

[image: jwt token with acr tag]

Comment: @Rikkert Check out this other answer for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688455/in-azure-ad-b2c-should-the-acr-or-tfp-claim-have-the-policy-name/46697200#46697200

Comment: @Pytry This is only configurable when using the regular B2C_1_SiUpIn Policy. You don't have a "Token, session & SSO config" screen when using Custom Policies. You have to configure it with xml files.

Comment: @spottedmahn I don't see the 'acr' claim. I only see a claim "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference". It's value is the (correct) policyname. But I want to put the policyname in an outputclaim. And I can't write ClaimTypeReferenceId="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference" because then I get the "ClaimType not found" error when uploading the xml file.