# In Azure AD B2C, Should the ACR or TFP Claim Have the Policy Name?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

[According to this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens), the `Policy Name` should be in the TFP (Trust Framework Policy) claim but it is showing up in the ACR claim.  I started with the [Starter Pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack)

[image]

---

**ID Token w/ ACR Claim** containing the `Policy Name`

[image: id token w/ acr claim]

---

Also, further down in the documentation it says the ACR is where the Policy Name will be:

[image: acr documentation]

[Related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683705/how-can-i-return-the-policyid-claim-after-executing-my-custom-signupsignin-polic/46688268#46688268)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is recommended you issue the policy ID in the "tfp" claim. If you are creating custom policies, then you can issue this by configuring the "JwtIssuer" technical profile. You can learn more about this at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-manage-sso-and-token-configuration).

Answer (score 3):

This is actually configurable, so it does not matter so long as you configure your application to use whichever you choose.

Go to `B2C_1_YourPolicy -> edit -> 'Token, session & SSO config'` and flip the toggle for the "Claim representing policy ID" field. You can choose either `tfp` or `acr`.

[image: azure portal]