# How to setup app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication for handling different Azure B2C custom policies?

Tags: azure, owin, azure-ad-b2c, claims, policies

I read this article: [Secure ASP.NET Web API 2 using Azure AD B2C – Part 2](http://bitoftech.net/2016/08/24/secure-aspnet-web-api-2-azure-ad-b2c/)

At step 3 `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` is called 3 times... one for each policy.

I'm testing with only 2 policies: `SignInPolicyId` and `SignUpPolicyId`.

However when I do:

```cs
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(CreateBearerOptionsForPolicy(SignInPolicyId))  
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(CreateBearerOptionsForPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
```

and pass a `Provider` with its `OnValidateIdentity` to deal with validating claims, etc. I then try to filter by the policy like this:

```cs
private OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions CreateBearerOptionsForPolicy(string policy)
{
    var metadataEndpoint = string.Format(AadInstance, TenantId, policy);

    TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // This is where you specify that your API only accepts tokens from its own clients
        ValidAudience = ClientId,
        AuthenticationType = policy,
        NameClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier",
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };

    return new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(metadataEndpoint)),

        Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var policyName = identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference")?.Value;

                    if (policyName == B2CSignInPolicyId.ToLower()) // Sign In Only policy...
                    {
                        // Run specific code here for the policy that just sent a token back to the application...
                    }
```

**Problem:** the policy that is being executed @ Azure B2C, that is, the one that I'm calling is the `Sign In` policy, but the provider code is called twice. Once for each policy I registered including the `Sign Up` one.

**Question:** is there any better way of doing this so that we get the right Provider executed? If the `Sign In` policy is the one being called, execute just the `Sign In` provider and vice versa.

Edit:

I'm experiencing the same issue described here (sequence contains more than one element): http://bitoftech.net/2016/08/24/secure-aspnet-web-api-2-azure-ad-b2c/#comment-96913

This is the exception:

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager.d__20.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.HostAuthenticationFilter.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I got it working with only one call to:

```cs
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(CreateBearerOptionsForPolicy(DefaultPolicyId));
```

Note that I passed just a default policy, let's say the `Sign In` one.

For other policies it's also hitting the `OnValidateIdentity` delegate.

Regarding the policy name we need to customize the custom policy even further and return the Policy Id claim as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-manage-sso-and-token-configuration).

This other [answer](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/q/46683705/114029) @ SO helps in understanding that.

With that setup, when the policy is executed we can get the policy name by looking at `TFP` (Trusted Framework Policy) claim like in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hey @LenielMaccaferri I know this is a long time ago, but are you willing to share the code from the AzureAdB2CExtensions class you created?